# Promise { <pending> } ' why is it still pending?' How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, response

So the result in the console shows as -

```
Promise { <pending> } ' why is it still pending?'
[ { _id: 5a7c6552380e0a299fa752d3, username: 'test', score: 44 } ]
```

So it tells me Promise { pending } but then follows with the answer that I wanted to see which is -

```
[ { _id: 5a7c6552380e0a299fa752d3, username: 'test', score: 44 } ]
```

but how can I fix that promise pending section, it's a console.log that I run at the bottom of the code.

```
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) 
              reject(err);
          else
              resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

resolveAfter1() // resolve function
    .then((result)=>{console.log(result);})
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);})

    async function asyncCall() {
      var result = await resolveAfter1();
      // console.log(result);
    }

    console.log(asyncCall(), ' why is it still pending?');
```

Comment: Because you don't wait for `asyncCall` with `await`.

Comment: What do you recommend, I should use instead?

Comment: @Andrew First port of call ► [**async function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) && [**await**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) || [**How to “await” for a callback to return?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104199/how-to-await-for-a-callback-to-return)

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
console.log(asyncCall(), ' why is it still pending?');
```

With:

```
async function run() {
   console.log(await asyncCall());
}

run();
```

You were printing the result of `asyncCall` which is an `async function`. Async functions wrap their returned result in a `Promise`, and if you want the actual value which the promise resolved to, you have to use `await someAsyncFunc()`.

Put in a simple example:

```js
async function asyncCall() {
   return 1;
}

async function run() {
   console.log(asyncCall()); // this doesn't wait for the Promise to resolve
   console.log(await asyncCall()); // this does
}

run();
```

Comment: That gives me undefined, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are console.log a **AsyncFunction** directly without await, it will return you a unresolved Promise object

```js
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve('a'), 100)
  })
}

async function asyncCall() {
  var result = await resolveAfter1();
  return result
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await asyncCall(), ' It is not pending anymore!!!!')
})()
```