# node 8: converting a promise/callback structure to async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I've got the following code block:

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  if (checkCondition()) {
    res(getValue())
  } else {
    getValueAsync((result) => {
      res(result)
    })
  }
}).then((value) => {
  doStuff(value)
})
```

I'd like to convert this to use `async`/`await`, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I know when you're working exclusively with promises, you replace the calls to `then()` with `value = await ...`, but How do I make this work with callbacks?  Is it possible?

Comment: [async/await is not magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37104225/542251) seems to be the important thing to note here

Comment: @Liam so it sounds like the answer is what I want is impossible, and I'm stuck with promises for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to make sure you are in an `async` function to begin with. Then it could be something along the lines of:

```
async function example() {
  let value = (checkCondition() ? getValue() : await getValueAsync());
  doStuff(value);
}
await example();
```

This, however, assumes that you can modify `getValueAsync` as well, to make it an `async` function or to make it return a `Promise`. Assuming `getValueAsync` has to take a callback, there is not that much we can do:

```
async function example() {
  let value = (checkCondition()
      ? getValue()
      : await new Promise(res => getValueAsync(res))
    );
  doStuff(value);
}
await example();
```

You still gain the benefit of not having to create the full `Promise` chain yourself. But, `getValueAsync` needs to be wrapped in a `Promise` in order to be usable with `await`. You should carefully consider whether this kind of a change is worth it for you. E.g. if you are in control of most of the codebase and / or most of the functions you are calling are already `async` / return `Promise`s.

Comment: could it? `getValueAsync` doesn't return a promise. It calls a callback.

Comment: @ewok Please see the edited answer.