# React setstate callback does not work after initial use

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-state-management

I have a function that, when initialized, takes a previously set state and uses it to make an api call with axios:

```
 _onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true }, () => {
      axios.get(this.state.currentPath)
        .then(res=>{
          console.log(res.data)
          this.props.loadCards(res.data) 
        })
        this.setState({refreshing: false})
    });
  }
```

I can see that the promise is never completed, and that a response is not given.

However, on the first use after the page loads, the function works correctly; it's only on subsequent usage that it does not work.

When the get request does not work, I've taken the path that's been stored in state, made a request in postman, and received a valid result.

Comment: You're doing `this.setState({refreshing: false})` right after you fire off the call to axios, not after it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

you should cancel the refreshing in the `finally` block

```
get(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
.finally(() => this.setState({refreshing: false}))
```

Comment: Note that `Promise.prototype.finally` is only available in current browsers (no IE 11 or even edge 17) and node 10.x+.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Thank you for your response. @JaredSmith

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix the issue?

```
_onRefresh = () => {
this.setState({ refreshing: true }, () => {
  axios.get(this.state.currentPath)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data)
      this.props.loadCards(res.data)
      this.setState({refreshing: false}) // moved this line into the then block
    })    
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_onRefresh =async () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true }, () => {
   await axios.get(this.state.currentPath) //you might need to handle promises to get this working.
        .then(res=>{
          console.log(res.data)
          this.props.loadCards(res.data) 
        })
        this.setState({refreshing: false})
    });
  }
```

Comment: I receive the error: `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104199/how-to-await-for-a-callback-to-return Please refer here this will resolve the issues