# Publishing Dialogflow User Input to Firebase Issue With Inline Editor

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

To sum up the problem I was facing with Dialogflow integration with Firebase, The user input isn't publishing onto the Firebase/cloud FireStore when it should. I am intending the parameter that I named Locations to be published into the collection I named as Location.

First, I followed a tutorial in which the user enables slot filling for the intent which I have done. The Intent name is Location.

Next, on Firebase I opened up the database which corresponded with my bot project ID and created a collection with the identifier name: Location.

Next I attempted to publish the user input for the parameter (named Locations) using the inline editor

**package.json Code**:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.9.0",
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

**nodejs code:**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  function getLocationHandler(agent) {
    let location = agent.parameters.location;
    db.collection("Location").add({ Location: location });
  }
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Location', getLocationHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your database write code is incorrect. Writing to Firestore works like this:

```
const doc = db.collection('Location').doc()
const data = {
  Location: location,
}
await doc.set(data)
```

Also, note that you need to await the set call as it is async and returns a promise. For more information, have a look [how to add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js).

You then also need to make sure your callback `getLocationHandler(agent)` provided in `agent.handleRequest(intentMap);` also awaits correctly, meaning:

To be able to use `await` for the Firestore write in `getLocationHandler(agent)`, `getLocationHandler` needs to be `async`. Then you need to make sure that your cloud function `functions.https.onRequest(...)` does not *finish* before the `getLocationHandler` completed correctly.

Depending on the signature of `agent.handleRequest` (which I unfortunately do not know) you can await this call or if it only accepts a void callback, you would have to create a promise before, complete it at the end of `getLocationHandler` and await this promise at the end of the `onRequest`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104199/how-to-await-for-a-callback-to-return) for details about this.