# Use response from a Nodejs spawn process

Tags: node.js, process, spawn

I've seen some people talking about this in a couple other posts, but none of them are very too the point.

```
async function decodeCopyCommand(toDecode) {

  let output = '';
  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["/home/isaac/Documents/gitlab/aievr-web/exfil_webpage/monitor.py","--decode", JSON.stringify(toDecode)]);

  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    output+=data
  });

  // Wait 2 seconds before parsing output. Otherwise output is 'undefined'
  await setTimeout(2000);
  console.log("Waited 2s");
  const jsonOutput = JSON.parse(output)
  console.log(jsonOutput)

  return jsonOutput
}
```

Waiting 2 seconds for the `pythonProcess.stdout.on()` to update the output variable is all I've been able to come up with. It works but is also very stupid and prone to errors.

Is there a better way to wait for the `output` variable to update with the data from the response?

Cheers

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/child_process.html#event-close

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to listen for the close event on the child process as suggested by tkausl.

Here is the updated code:

```
async function decodeCopyCommand(toDecode) {

  let output = '';
  let processRunning = true
  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["/home/isaac/Documents/gitlab/aievr-web/exfil_webpage/monitor.py","--decode", JSON.stringify(toDecode)]);

  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    output+=data
  });

  pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    processRunning = false
  });

  while(processRunning){
    await setTimeout(200); // Wait 200ms before checking processRunning again
  }

  if (!processRunning){
    return JSON.parse(output)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to promisify the `spawn` callback.

Take a look at [How to "await" for a callback to return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104199/how-to-await-for-a-callback-to-return)

It would end up looking something like this:

```js
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const pythonData = (toDecode) => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

  const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["/home/isaac/Documents/gitlab/aievr-web/exfil_webpage/monitor.py","--decode", JSON.stringify(toDecode)]);

  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    resolve(data)
  });

  pythonProcess.stdout.on('error', (code) => {
    reject(`error with code ${code}`)
  });

})


async function decodeCopyCommand(toDecode) {

  const output = await pythonData(toDecode)

  const jsonOutput = JSON.parse(output)
  console.log(jsonOutput)

  return jsonOutput
}
```